# Backbone.js - how to have the bookmark not change if visiting to a new one fails

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), and have a query. Say my user is at *http://www.foo.com/#about*, and clicks on a link to go to *http://www.foo.com/#profile*. But I don't want to take him to *#profile* if he hasn't logged in. So, if he hasn't logged in, the bookmark **#about shouldn't change**. Unable to know how to achieve this. Would need help. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but why do you have the link to #profile if your user is not allowed to click it? Rather than hack around disabling the link why simply not show it in the first place?

Comment: Say, on clicking the #profile link, I would display a login dialog, and go to #profile only if he successfully logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to *bind* a *click event* into the *profile link* and add the logic there, also use `Backbone.Router` to manage the navigation history. Something like:

```
// code simplified and not tested
App.Router = new Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "about":  "about",
    "profile": "profile",
  },

  # [...] your routes functions here
});

App.MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#menu",

  events: {
    "click #profile": "showProfile"
  },

  showProfile: function(){
    if( App.currentUser.logged? ) {
      App.MyRouter.navigate( "profile", {trigger: true} );
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will be helpful.Any other patterns are also welcome as I am trying a single page application and would love to pick the best patterns